# Remotely activate GPS function

Tags: android, gps

i recently asked a question for implementation of toast message when the GPS is not enabled. 
of this i knew it was possible.

Is it possible to automatically activate the GPS function in the background.

When i **remotely activate** the application in the background. can i activate **the GPS** from the phone itself aswell without the other phone reporting anything to the user ?

the situation is like this.

*we have a project named ParentalControl Application. So a parent has to be able to track its child remotely.*

does anyone have suggestion or ideas ... ?

if it is of anyhelp 
this is the code i'm using at the moment.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView TxtLat;
    TextView TxtLong;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TxtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtLat);
        TxtLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtLong);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // implementation of TOASTS
        if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " You can improve the accuracy by turning on the GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        LocationListener ll = new myLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    }
        class myLocationListener implements LocationListener
        {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
            {
                if (location != null)
                {
                    double pLong = location.getLongitude();
                    double pLat = location.getLatitude();

                    TxtLat.setText(Double.toString(pLat));
                    TxtLong.setText(Double.toString(pLong));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can't enable the GPS if it's turned off in settings. You can however request a location updates if it is enabled, and you can do this remotely. For example you could send a Google Cloud Message with a specific extra in the intent which could do this.

Comment: so ... i can request some sort of update, in wich we pull the location of the user. 

an idea 

if the user(child) sends an textmessage , can i customize my application so the location of the child get's send along with the textmessage ... ?

if so i only have to lock Textmesssaging when GPS is disabled. so the child is forced to turn on the GPS in order to communicate... 

correct ? or am i missing something ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't really "lock" messaging, as there isn't a way to intercept/alter a message sent using the SMS API. So, even if you were to write your own messaging app that forces the enabling of GPS to add location info to the outgoing message, any other SMS app can still send a message without forcing GPS. Even in KitKat, with its _default SMS app_ designation, if an app has the `SEND_SMS` permission, it is able to send SMS messages.

Comment: correct BUT 

we are developing an entire Launcher wich enables/disables Default apps to our own liking , wich is why we wrote our own applications for calls and Messages even for contact storage we created a custom app with database. 

so i don't think that there is any way to send Messages aslong as we disable the default application "by default" and only unlock the custom application when the GPS is activated ... ? correct ? 

or no mather the way we turn the table , there will always be a way to send Messages ???

Comment: I'm not certain, as I've never written a Launcher and don't know to what extent you can limit system settings, app installs, etc. Keep in mind that all it would take is the user being able to install another app with the `SEND_SMS` permission, be it through the Play Store, a third-party source from a website, or even connecting it to their own IDE. I hear kids are smarter these days.